# SQL query to find sum using group by

Tags: sql

SQL query to find sum of quantity of similar prodid only if quantity in each prodid greater than 1.
SQL query:

```
Select ProdID,sum(quantity) 
  From product 
 Where quantity >1 
 Group by ProdID
```

What logical error in above query ?? [image]

The Result should be :

```
ProdID  Quantity
------  --------
 102      11
```

Comment: What database platform?  what does "similar" mean?

Comment: Do you want to have `(101,2), (102,5),(102,6)` as result ..?

Comment: Result should be like( 102 ,5+6 ) 101 is not included as in one row it's quantity is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtering in the `having`:

```
Select ProdID, sum(quantity)
from product
group by ProdID
having min(quantity) > 1;
```

The use of `min()` assumes that `quantity` is non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

For such purpose include also `quantity` column in the `group by` expression with `having` clause

```
Select ProdID,quantity
  from product 
 group by ProdID, quantity
 having sum(quantity) >1
```

**Edit** ( *due to your last comment* ) : Use `not in` as below

```
Select ProdID, sum(quantity) 
  from product 
 where ProdID not in ( select ProdID from product p where quantity = 1 ) 
 group by ProdID
```

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/ZWN44728)</kbd>